# Laravel 5: how to put admin controllers in a folder?

Tags: routes, namespaces, laravel-5, controllers

I'm creating my first admin panel in Laravel 5.  I would like to organize my controllers like:

```
Http
    Controllers
        Admin
            DashboardController.php
        Controller.php
        WelcomeController.php
```

But I'm having some trouble getting this to work.

DashboardController.php is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return \View::make('admin/dashboard');
    }
}

?>
```

And my routes contain:

```
Route::group(array('namespace'=>'Admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));
});

// Eventually I will check for authentication using:
// Route::group(array('before' => 'auth', 'namespace'=>'Admin'), function()...
```

When I navigate to /dashboard, the error I get is:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController does not exist

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5 has much stricter adherence to namespace standards that previous versions of Laravel.

This means that changing folder structure also changes the namespace the autoloader looks in for a class.

In this case, you've added the namespace `Admin` to your DashboardController.

Your declaration `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` should be changed to

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
```

Likewise, if you make further changes to the folder structure, such as adding a new sub-folder under Admin for `SuperAdmin`, you'll need to add that namespace to the classes within that folder. This applies to other folders as well, like your `Handlers`, `Events`, etc.

If you start changing the folder structure, it's best to understand the namespace concept for PHP. Here's a good tutorial to learn quickly: http://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained

Comment: @clone45 though, this is the accepted the answer, but the content is wrong. you don't need to follow any type of special folder structure. you can put the class whatever folder you want. but you just have to make sure, your namespace is tracked by composer and while dumping, its correspondent entry goes into `autoload_classmap.php`. as long as composer can found it, it will include it for you __no matter whatever folder it is in__.

Answer (score 4):

there is a misconception that *Laravel 5 now forces a special folder structure.*

but **No, it does not**

the problem with your code is this:

```
Route::group(array('namespace'=>'Admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/dashboard', 
    array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));
});
```

you are using a namespace `Admin` where as in your controller, there is no such namespace. hence, laravel will complain.

if you remove this `array('namespace=>'Admin')`, your code will run fine.

**But** if you want to keep the namespace, then there's a way,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin; \\Add the admin part.

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return \View::make('admin/dashboard');
    }
}

?>
```

Now, it will be accessible.

**Note #1:** *But it does not mean DashboardController must reside in `admin` folder*

In fact, it can stay in any folder. **As long as you keep the correct namespace** it is same as previous versions. all you need to do is, run a

```
composer dump-autoload -o
or
php composer.phar dump-autoload -o
```

and composer will add the file in autoload.

Comment: I'll look into the code on this, but it makes sense to me. I was under the belief that Laravel was looking at folder structure as well. From a maintenance standpoint though, I'd suggest putting classes in the same folder structure as their namespace.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.1 and composer dump-autoload -o solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try following code with folder name in namespace, you must have to use folder as namespace i.e it follow folder name as namespace App/Http/Controller/Admin

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return \View::make('admin/dashboard');
    }
}

?>
```

routing remain as it is

```
Route::group(array('namespace'=>'Admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));
});
```